# reinterpret_cast from type casts away qualifiers cuando el argumento de la plantilla es un puntero

Tags: c++, c++11, template

Estoy haciendo una envoltura C++ para una librería en C. No quiero incluir las cabeceras de C dentro de los `.hpp`, así que trabajo con predeclaración de tipos. Igualmente, intentando no cometer *demasiados* comportamientos indefinidos, la mayoría de mis punteros son `void *`, y voy *moldeando* según es necesario.

Me ha surgido un error *curioso*. En un punto, tengo que realizar un *moldeado* desde `const void *` a un tipo predeclarado. Concretamente, a la versión `const` del tipo. Pero al compilador parece que no le gusta *demasiado*:

> #### (g++)
>
> error: reinterpret_cast from type `const void*` to type `uv_loop_s*` casts away qualifiers
>
> #### (clang++)
>
> error: reinterpret_cast from `const void *` to `uv_loop_s *const` casts away qualifiers

Lo *curioso* es que **no estoy haciendo un moldeado a `uv_loop_s *`**, sino a **`const uv_loop_s *`**:

```
return reinterpret_cast< const T >( raw( ) );
```

y la función `raw( )` está declarada como

```
const void *raw( ) const noexcept
```

Un ejemplo mínimo verificable:

```
typedef struct uv_loop_s uv_loop_t;

template< typename T > struct Base {
    Base( ) : m_uv( nullptr ) { }

    void *raw( ) noexcept { return m_uv; }

    const void *raw( ) const noexcept { return m_uv; }

    T uv( ) noexcept { return reinterpret_cast< T >( raw( ) ); }

    const T uv( ) const noexcept { return reinterpret_cast< const T >( raw( ) ); }

private:
    void *m_uv;
};

struct Loop : public Base< uv_loop_t * > {
    bool test( ) const {
        return uv( );
    }
};
```

<sub>**Nota**: puede [probarse aquí (g++)](https://tio.run/##hZHBbsMgDIbvPIWPaaW9QBPtsPOOvUeUelMkAhaYtFWVZ88MSdatazVOxvb/23wYopdPY6aJL4RH/IDIIRmGNLTWe2rjd8S1Uow9Wc3YQG53ukfYw@uqedMR4apATg4r2MAO@jYNFbhkLXGQzBVGVVoG3x1hG/Qp9zmPZ4PEUg7IKbiiq9de413k34o59Y9uD3n4I/uAnWMMJNfW6MhNfkgFi/nmbvLq82zoX7dVd@9JoRsE4O4HgrKxGgXvwvFdcAs5SgfbmYKyuf0CbAX4DPngvQXGyLfV5kI@y2Zl77pkR5kxTV8) o [aquí (clang++)](https://tio.run/##hZHBbsMgDIbvPIWPaaW9QBPtsPOOvUeUelMkAhaYtFWVZ88MSdatazVOxvb/23wYohdjtfucJr4QHvEDIodkGNLQWu@pjd8R10ox9mQ1YwO53ekeYQ@vq@ZNR4SrAjk5rGADO@jbNFTgkrXEQTJXGFVpGXx3hG3Qp9znPJ4NEks5IKfgiq5ee413kX8r5tQ/uj3k4Y/sA3aOMZBcW6MjN/khFSzmm7vJq8@zoX/dVt29J4VuEIC7HwjKxmoUvAvHd8Et5CgdbGcKyub2C7AV4DPkg/cWGCPfVpsL@Syblb3rkh1lxjR9AQ)</sub>

1. ¿ Que estoy haciendo mal ?
2. ¿ Cómo lo soluciono ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El tipo por el que se traduce T se trata como un paquete indivisible así, cuando tu pones

```
const T func();
```

Tu estás esperando que se convierta en

```
uv_loop_t const* func();
```

Es decir, un puntero constante... pero la realidad es que se convierte en algo un poco diferente:

```
uv_loop_t * const func();
```

Es decir, un puntero en el que lo único constante es la dirección de memoria apuntada.

Para solucionar el problema tienes que meter el puntero de forma explícita:

```
typedef struct uv_loop_s uv_loop_t;

template< typename T > struct Base {
    Base( ) : m_uv( nullptr ) { }

    void *raw( ) noexcept { return m_uv; }

    const void *raw( ) const noexcept { return m_uv; }

    T* uv( ) noexcept { return reinterpret_cast< T* >( raw( ) ); }

    const T* uv( ) const noexcept { return reinterpret_cast< const T * >( raw( ) ); }

private:
    void *m_uv;
};

struct Loop : public Base< uv_loop_t > {
    bool test( ) const {
        return uv( );
    }
};
```

Comment: @Trauma ¿Dónde pasa eso de que `uv_loop_t*` pasa a ser constante? eso solo pasa con las llamadas a funciones `const`

Comment: @Trauma lo de `const` te lo ha dicho PaperBirdMaster... la solución que yo te he propuesto funciona igual de bien en [ambos casos](https://tio.run/##hVE7b4MwEN79K24kSF06BpShc8fsiDiXCsnYln0mqSJ@Oz0bQx5NVU/H@Xv5Q1r79iXlNNG3xSOewJMLkiAMjTLGNn6dqBKCsLeqJawhwnXbI@xht3A@Wo9wFcAnjgVsYAt9E4YCdFDKkuPNFUaRIIPpjlC69hxx2uBFoiW@dkjB6cSrFqw02tMjY179w9uXEN1f6TvsNKGz/NnI1lMdwbsCsvzmyXtV@sv3t95KfFa1rhu4xO1dDSm1GLni3OUnV87t2XBQnUx11rc/wZXPNR@MUUDo6ZZsvognB0uxq7QdH0nvkbXg8cLpNfAj8ticgpbUGV3cGZeL1Cr/Ajy/NDuO1TT9AA)

Comment: Perdona, que me he liado. Pero con tu solución, ahora `uv( )` devuelve un `uv_struct_t **` (doble puntero) ... y me *descogorza* todo el código por otro lado ... ¡ Que asco me dan las plantillas !

Comment: @Trauma si te devuelve eso es que estás haciendo algo mal... fíjate que yo hago `Base<uv_loop_t>`, y `uv` queda así `T* uv()`, como `T` es de tipo `uv_loop_t`, `T*` será un **puntero simple**

Comment: ¡ Ah *carajo* ! Tienes razón, no me dí cuenta y había dejado el parámetro de plantilla como puntero. ¡ Funciona ! Pero que conste que las plantillas me siguen dando asco :-(

Comment: @Trauma jajajajaja, te entiendo perfectamente :)

Answer (score 1):

Prueba esto:

```
struct Loop : public Base< const uv_loop_t * > {
//                         ^^^^^ <--- Soy constante
    bool test( ) const {
        return uv( );
    }
};
```

---

La propagación de `const` sigue unas normas confusas que ni me se de memoria ni voy a buscar<sup>1</sup> pero de manera muy resumida una de las cosas que dice es que marcar tipos trivialmente copiables como constantes es absurdo<sup>2</sup>:

```
   const int funcion() { return {}; }
// ^^^^^ <--- Este const es absurdo, como puede verse en la siguiente línea:
   int valor = funcion();
// ^^^ <--- ¡No es const!
```

Los punteros son tipos trivialmente copiables así que no propagan `const` de la manera que crees, si mostramos el nombre de un tipo podemos ver un comportamiento *inesperado*:

```
template <typename T> std::string TypeName()
{
    auto name = typeid(T).name();
    int status = 0;
 
    std::unique_ptr<char, void(*)(void*)> res {
        abi::__cxa_demangle(name, NULL, NULL, &status),
        std::free
    };
 
    return ((status == 0) ? res.get() : name);
}

#define CHIVATO(X) std::cout << "'" #X "' = " << TypeName<X>() << '\n'

int main()
{
    CHIVATO(int);
    CHIVATO(const int);
    CHIVATO(int *);
    CHIVATO(const int *);
    CHIVATO(int * const);
    CHIVATO(const int * const);

    return 0;
}
```

El código anterior muestra:

> ```
> 'int' = int
> 'const int' = int
> 'int *' = int*
> 'const int *' = int const*
> 'int * const' = int*
> 'const int * const' = int const*
> ```

Podemos ver que `const int`, `int * const` y `const int *const` han perdido un `const` por el camino al pasar a parámetro de plantilla, si lo probamos con un parámetro plantilla pasado a otra plantilla (como es tu caso):

```
template <typename T>
struct hazme_constante
{
    hazme_constante() { CHIVATO(const T); }
//                              ^^^^^ <--- Añade const al parámetro de la plantilla
};

int main()
{
    hazme_constante<int>{};
    hazme_constante<const int>{};
    hazme_constante<int *>{};
    hazme_constante<const int *>{};
    hazme_constante<int *const >{};
    hazme_constante<const int *const>{};

    return 0;
}
```

Vemos el mismo comportamiento: añadir el `const` a posteriori al instanciar la plantilla dentro de otra plantilla no *fuerza* la propagación de `const` en los tipos trivialmente copiables.

Puedes ver los ejemplos en <kbd>[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##hVLBTsJAED13v2ICiXQJEs@l1hgvmhC8VMPBpFm3A2xCt7VsDUj4dpzdUgSEcOk27715M/N2ZVHcyrnQ0@22rbScVylCqPKFKVFkEfvDzKpApSf5IZZhlperQ0Qul@JT9WeHGHkpPY0YMINZMRdm56ZFhhBHsDBpENQiiAkfEe5ztmaeqEwOTnYPrn/qx7yvHT9gntKGioWpFsTfDaiB57wqrb4qTApThnImyh5851TZ5b49uzyCEhdA9h6NGgRJIpciSTGjEOboW/cejN6Gw@Z7U/fgPapw/pMSkXkb17BEU5UafL8ZhCbh8GBb9KdofA6B24Dm3TDWTnGiNMLT88v7Y/zqj3m9vcwrA2EIrU4L2mM6aKGWBZo8wnFEVgR0PnSHnQ@SUYaVNDATPxkmMtc0kjZogzyByGq9n8GhEPMBbBjtxGyqmVC6voJGRaiN/LjoBLSV3bOqY9gB4MgL6j25u9EmH7u9BU/2CakoWtPw/4i953naNbtSeUngqFp11cH9OtX@xdzZB7Hd/gI)</kbd>.

---

- <sup>1</sup>A no ser que sea completamente necesario para ganar el visto bueno en la respuesta no voy a bucear en el estándar un lunes por la mañana.
- <sup>2</sup>No dice eso exactamente, estoy hablando de memoria.

Comment: (1) y (2) -> Me basta con una explicación *básica*. Como dices, *meterle mano* al estandard ... un lunes por la mañana ... ¡ Se me pone el vello de punta !

Comment: upppsss ... no me vale. Dentro de `struct Loop` hago llamadas a funciones C que reciben un `uv_loop_t *`, que ahora pasa a ser constante. Estamso hablando de cambiar **todas** mis llamadas a las funciones C que intengo *wrappear* ... ¿ No habría otra forma que no implique pasar `const` como parámetro de plantilla ?

Comment: Si los tipos pueden ser variados, tendrás que especializar para puntero. Si los tipos sólo pueden ser punteros, redacta la clase para que así quede reflejado.